# We have a query regarding GCP buckets, Can we put the GCS bucket behind the VPN, is it feasible in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vpn, bucket

We have a query regarding GCP buckets, Can we put the GCS bucket behind the
VPN, is it feasible in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set a private Google Access configuration, and play with your DNS to use the VPN to reach the GCP APIs. [Here the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access)